# DBLINK works in SQL Developer, not in APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When I run this in SQL Developer, it works fine.  This is connected to a PV_COMPLIANCE Schema.

```
  select * from ARGUS_CUSTOM.dlp_case_narrative_rowid@ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB;
```

When I crate an APEX app an use this query as the source for an interactive report, I get:

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
```

The APEX app is connected to the PV_COMPLIANCE schema.  Obviously it doesnt work in APEX SQL Workshop either.

Any ideas??

Update:  Appears doing SELECT * on a table which has a CLOB column in it, over a DBLINK is what is generating this error message.  Strange. I can select from the DB Link, but only if I select non-CLOB columns.  Feels like a bug to me (in term of the error being presented anyway).

Comment: In an APEX session, you're not actually connected as schema "PV_COMPLIANCE". You're connected as a generic APEX schema and I believe that does an ```ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA PV_COMPLIANCE``` command. I'm not sure what the issue is you're encountering, but this might give you a clue in which direction to start looking.

Comment: Hi, so if its running AS PV_COMPLIANCE, why isn't it able to access the DB Link?

Comment: "set current_schema" does not change your authid... it gives you no privs to that user whatsoever. All it does is prefix that schema to any unqualified object names so you don't have to write out the schema name every time. You can't use someone else's private dblink... you'll have to create a public dblink or one under the apex schema.

Comment: How does APEX work at all then if it connects to a schemas as other users and has no access to the schema objects?? Why are DB links special, how can APEX read the tables in my schema when I did no explicit grants to APEX system\service accounts.

Comment: Private DB links can only be used *directly* by the schema owner. APEX has the ability to see and execute objects in the app schema using privileges granted to it automatically when the app schema is added to the APEX workspace, but cannot reference the DB link because it does not *become* the schema owner (does not connect *as*) and there is no privilege possible to allow the link access. Private DB links can only be used *indirectly* by other users, as through a view like `create or replace view v1 as select * from table@dblink`, then granting select on the view to other users.

Comment: Private DB links are *different* from all other DB objects: they can only be created by and used directly by their owner. It is not possible to grant select privileges on them to other users, nor to the "ANY" privileges apply to them.

Comment: thanks @pmdba.  But how does the APEX account access simple objects like tables, when I didnt explicitly provide a GRANT. I always assumed it maybe connected as the schema owner

Comment: `APEX_PUBLIC_USER` has access to the API owned by `APEX_XXXXXX` (the primary APEX version schema, e.g., APEX_220100), which has the ability to execute specific commands with elevated DBA-like privileges (similar to the "ANY" privileges). The API knows which workspace, app and APEX user are making a request and controls access to those privileges accordingly.

Comment: But not DB links as I guess that takes them out to another DB they dont own? is that the reasoning, its the system boundary it violates

Comment: @pmdba for reference this actually does work, just not if there is a CLOB in the underlying remote table.  Bit of a bizarre error message, so it appears APEX_PUBLIC_USER can access DB links.   If I don't do select *, but select non-CLOB columns its fine.